# Virtually chroot clients using mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, ssl, client-certificates

I am attempting to setup a webdav website for various clients to upload/download files. However I don't want each client to see the other clients' data. Each client uses SSL client certificates to authenticate, so I would like to chroot them into their own directory tree.

**For example:**

- https://example.com/webdav/upload
- Should map to filesystem location
- /somewebroot/webdav/SSL_USERNAME/upload

I thought that I could use mod_rewrite for this but my rules seem to send me into an infinite redirection loop. Any thoughts?

```
Alias /webdav /somewebroot/webdav
<Directory /somewebroot/webdav>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /webdav

    RewriteCond %{SSL:SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN} ADMIN #The admin does not get chrooted
    RewriteRule .* - [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^%{SSL:SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN}/(.*)
    RewriteRule ^(.*) %{SSL:SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN}/$1 [L]
</Directory>
```

Comment: From what I can tell, the REQUEST_URI variable acts differently in a redirect compared to a normal request and this might be what is breaking this solution.

Comment: I like the concept. Do you have something to verify the certificate? I will look at that mod-rewrite directive to see if I can get some advice.

Comment: I'm running my own certificate authority for this and other servers, so to validate that a client is allowed they just have to have a client cert that is correctly signed by the CA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for this is fairly simple once you figure out that "RewriteCond" does not support server variables in the PATTERN. So you have to get it into the pattern by using a backreference. Also "RewriteCond" does not use the "RewriteBase" directive so you also have to take that into account as well.

```
Alias /webdav /somewebroot/webdav
<Directory /somewebroot/webdav>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /webdav

    RewriteCond %{SSL:SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN} ADMIN #The admin does not get chrooted
    RewriteRule .* - [L]

    RewriteCond %{SSL:SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN}::%{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)::/webdav/\1/(.*)
    RewriteRule ^(.*) %{SSL:SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN}/$1 [L]
</Directory>
```